# I would like to shorten multiple file names all at once in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, batch-processing

I would like to shorten multiple file names all at once. (file names below) I want to keep the first 4 characters and the R1 or R2 so they read D24I_R2.fastq or C24F_R1.fastq. Is there a way in terminal to do this all at once so I don't have to rename every individual file with mv.

Some examples:

```
C11F_S16_L001_R1_001.fastq -> C11F_R1.fastq
A11C_S32_L001_R2_001.fastq -> A11C_R2.fastq
C11F_S16_L001_R2_001.fastq -> C11F_R2.fastq
```

Comment: Wow. No need for every file name, I've edited it down.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the folder of `*.fastq` files, execute this command:

```
for f in *.fastq; do mv "$f" "${f:0:4}${f:13:3}${f:20:6}"; done
```

Comment: Yikes! Please put some double quotes around `"$f"` quickly!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. This works but somehow deletes the second file when I have two files C11F_S16_L001_R1_001.fastq  and C11F_S16_L001_R2_001.fastq

Comment: what about for i in $(ls *fastq | grep "[A-Z]_R" | cut -f 1 -d '_' | sort | uniq); done

Comment: @user6046940 How did you run the command? I run in different ways and no file will be deleted. Your new command has no actions. Inner expression extracts `C11F` in this case if you add a `*` in grep pattern: `grep "[A-Z]*_R"`.